# Dartium 1.21.0 build on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: build, dart, dartium

Try to build Dartium 1.21.0 on Ubuntu 16.10, following the instructions https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building-Dartium

Replacing `gclient config --deps-file tools/deps/dartium.deps/DEPS --name=src/dart https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk.git`

with `gclient config --deps-file tools/deps/dartium.deps/DEPS --name=src/dart https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk.git@1.21.0`

With some minor tweaks, things works, until hit by same as this https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc/issues/221

Fixed in a later version of boringssl
https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/241364c6f4d44165ce2dc707b9ad141dcc880d1b

Chromium builds more or less of the box.

To continue, two options occur. To step the boringssl version and update the build files, alternativly find at matching os distro and version. What distro and version is Dartium build on? Goobuntu is based on Ubuntu, maybe 16.04 should be used? Or are there some other tweaks that will fix this?

ps. yes, I know at the moment the future of Dartium is uncertain (will use a build to look into the dart bindings towards blinks web idl).

Comment: I thonk there was something mentioned in Github (sdk repo) about library version conflicts - only on the phone now

Comment: Good to know. Then one could expect stepping boringssl version, just will cause conflicts with something else. Thanks!